# Excluding a vector from a list of data.frame

Tags: r

I have a list of 50 data.frame objects and each data.frame object contains 20 rows. I need to exclude a row or a vector at each iteration from each of the data.frame object.

The single iteration may look something like this:

```
to_exclude <- 0  # 0 will be replaced by the induction variable
training_temp <- lapply(training_data, function(x) {
                                        # Exclude the vector numbered to_exclude
                                        }
```

Regards

Comment: You want to remove the same row from every data.frame in your list?

Comment: something like: `lapply(training_data, function(x) x[-to_exclude,])` but I don't know that I fully understand your question...

Comment: If training_data is a list of data.frame you add x <- x[-to_exclude,]

Comment: @NathanG Yes, it would be the same row from each data.frame object. Which row is to be deleted will be determined  by loop or to_exclude object in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:10,y=1:10)

thelist <- list(df,df,df,df)

lapply(thelist, function(x) x[-c(1) ,] )
```

this will always remove the first row. Is this like what you want, or you want to remove rows based on a value?

This will always exclude the first column:

```
lapply(thelist, function(x) x[, -c(1) ] )

# because there are only two columns in this example you would probably 
# want to add drop = FALSe e.g.
# lapply(thelist, function(x) x[, -c(1), drop=FALSE ] )
```

so from your loop value:

```
remove_this_one <- 10
lapply(thelist, function(x) x[ -c(remove_this_one) ,] )
# remove row 10
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible that you can update the code a little so that the above process is represented in a loop and at each iteration we remove a row from each data.frame object represented by loop variable.

Comment: @Shahzad This `lapply` technique is the preferred method for "looping" in R.  The extension of the x[-remove,] syntax to a list should be fairly straight forward.  If not, I'd suggest looking at any of the excellent guides online.  Particularly, subsetting and list access.